# How do I left align data in pandas dataframe in tkinter label?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter, label

I am trying to display a pandas dataframe in a tkinter label in a popup window so that the user can easily see the data.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import Toplevel, Button, Tk
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 50)
pd.set_option('display.width',200)

root = Tk()

root.geometry("550x600+500+200")
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'title': {0: 'Sober', 1: 'Sober (8-Bit Tool Emulation) - 8-Bit Tool Emulation', 2: 'Sober (1993) [8-Bit Tool Emulation]', 3: 'Tool No. 2 (Sober)', 4: 'Sober (Made Famous by Tool)'}, 'artist': {0: 'Tool', 1: '8-Bit Arcade', 2: '8-Bit Arcade', 3: 'UltraRock', 4: 'Baby Lullaby Ensemble'}, 'endPos': {0: 38235, 1: 46546, 2: 56462, 3: 65970, 4: 74870}, 'match': {0: 100, 1: 29, 2: 37, 3: 57, 4: 35}, 'url': {0: 'https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Tool-4/sober?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=musixmatch-community%3A1409608317702', 1: 'https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/8-Bit-Arcade/Sober-8-Bit-Tool-Emulation-8-Bit-Tool-Emulation?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=musixmatch-community%3A1409608317702', 2: 'https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/8-Bit-Arcade/Sober-1993-8-Bit-Tool-Emulation?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=musixmatch-community%3A1409608317702', 3: 'https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/UltraRock/Tool-No-2-Sober?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=musixmatch-community%3A1409608317702', 4: 'https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Baby-Lullaby-Ensemble/Sober-Made-Famous-by-Tool?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=musixmatch-community%3A1409608317702'}}
)

def new_window() :
    win = Toplevel()
    win.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (1050, 270, root.winfo_x()  , root.winfo_y() + 600/4))
    tk.Label(win, text= df).grid(row=0, sticky=(tk.E))

Button(root, text = "open", command = new_window).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

but this is what the output looks like:

[image]

How do I make the values and headers left align?  Or is there another way to display this nicer?  I am not interested in using actual tables that look like excel, just want to make this more readable.

Comment: Use monospaced font and set `justify="left"`. Or use `Text` widget.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `TkFixedFont` to get a better result:

```
tk.Label(win, text=df, font='TkFixedFont').grid(row=0, sticky=(tk.E))
```

In addition, use [`df.to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) if you want more control (remove index, formatting numbers, etc)

```
text = df.to_string(index=False, max_colwidth=80)
tk.Label(win, text=text, font='TkFixedFont').grid(row=0, sticky=(tk.E))
```

Output:

[image]